# How can I set API url such that the API is accessible only to IP whitelisted clients while the web application itself remains accessible to all?

Tags: servlets, jax-rs, firewall, servlet-filters

I have a web application accessible to the public on a url, say *example.com*.
Now I want to provide a REST API to some clients to access the data on my server through a protected url, say *api.example.com.*
I do not want this API link to be accessible to the public and want to keep it protected through a firewall, only requests originating from whitelisted IPs should be able to consume the services.

**Hosting the API as a separate application seems like an overkill

**URL based filtering, say blocking example.com/funnyapi/1 while allowing api.example.com/funnyapi/1 also doesn't seem to be a proper solution.

I am new to REST api.

Please suggest how to go about this.

Comment: [`foobar.io` is registered, better use `example.com`] How do you want to restrict access to your API? HTTP Authentication? What do you use in your API, JAX-RS?

Comment: I want to restrict through IP validation at firewall level (if that is the norm). Yes, I am using JAX-RS.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't restrict the access based on the hostname, but on the URI path: a web application will usually server the same content, no matter which hostname you use.

Let's say you deployed the Jersey servlet using `web.xml` at `/contextPath/api`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can easily add a [`Filter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to your servlet which will filter according to the remote address. If you are using Tomcat there is already a filter that does that:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>AddressFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>192.168.\d+.\d+</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AddressFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>ApiServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, I'll consider adding also some `<security-contraint>`s:

```xml
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Api</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>apiUser</role-name> 
     </auth-constraint>
     <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
     </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Other ways to protect a RESTful API are described in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm).

**Edit:** If you are using another servlet container, you can create a filter like this:

```java
public class RemoteAddrFilter implements Filter {

   private Pattern allow;

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
      final String pattern = filterConfig.getInitParameter("allow");
      if (pattern != null) {
         allow = Pattern.compile(pattern);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      if (allow == null) {
         return;
      }
      final String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();

      if (allow.matcher(remoteAddr).matches()) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
      } else {
         if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: this answer presumes that OP is using Tomcat server, but this is nowhere explicitly stated in the question in its current form nor in previously asked questions of the OP. This answer won't work in other servers.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks, I didn't notice the lack of a `tomcat` tag or any mention of a servlet container. I edited the answer with an example of `Filter` independent from the container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PiotrP.Karwasz . Indeed this sounds like the ideal solution. I seem to have overcomplicated the question when a simple filter would have have been suffice. May be because I am new to JAX-RS, not knowing how it actually works.

Comment: @BalusC Piotr Regarding the security aspect, every request comes with a SHA-256 encrypted value of the parameters (separated by a delimeter) using a private key known only to the client and my server. I allow the request only if the checksum sent by client and the one generated by my server using same SHA-256 and private key matches. Am I making it safe enough. Please suggest.

Comment: Regarding the server, luckily I am using Tomcat only.

Comment: @bikram: if this solution solves your problem, you might consider accepting it (with the big checkmark `✔` sign beside the answer).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz As much as I would love to, it seems I will need to earn some reputation points first :)